# Customizing order of data in GridLayoutManager for Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

Currently I am using `GridLayoutManager` for my `RecyclerView`. The span is 2 and orientation is horizontal like below

```
  var myRecyclerView RecyclerView?
  myRecyclerView?.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)

  var myAdapter MyAdapter?
  myAdapter?.items = myItemList

  myRecyclerView?.adapter = myAdapter
```

In this case the way data gets laid out as below

```
  0, 3
  1, 4
  2, 5
```

However, the requirement is that the date should be ordered as below

```
  0, 1
  2, 3
  4, 5
```

I looked at `GridLayoutManager` or `Adapter` to manipulate the order but couldn't find one. Also, I can't sort on specific attribute of items to achieve this order.

Any suggestions would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Add to @Awm4n's anser above, I needed to add correct span count (2 in this case) and orientation as `LayoutManager.VERTICAL`. That did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think the default order when you use `GridLayoutManager(context, 2)` is

```
  0, 1
  2, 3
  4, 5
```

Comment: I wish it were that case, but it isn't :(